# Which algorithm can rank list based on history

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, ranking

- There are N unique items.
- There are K sorted lists, each list consists of a small subset of the items, each list does not contain the same item more than once.
- The input is an unsorted list of items.
- The algorithm should sort the list based on the K sorted lists.

Here is an example:

- There are 100 items : item1, item2, ..., item100
- There are some ranked lists available: List1: Item1>Item2>Item12, List2: Item12>item93>Item7, List3: Iterm1>Item3>Iterm97, List4: Iterm1>Iterm7>Item2

The input is: Iterm1, Item2, Iterm7 and Item98. The algorithm should sort the input based on those lists.

**In terms of machine learning** I am looking for an algorithm that can predict the 'right' order of a list of items (AKA active list) based on a training set of many partially ordered lists of items, each partial ordered list of items might contain other items that the active list does not contain.

Comment: I don't really unserstand what you mean ... maybe if you post an example ?

Answer (score 4):

Construct a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with input elements as nodes and define an edge from Itemi and Itemj if and only if Itemi appears immediately before Itemj in some list. Then you can obtain the desired order by doing a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the DAG.

Comment: why would the graph be acylic?

Comment: I was assuming that the union of the partial orders is acyclic. If it's not, what is your desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that the sorted lists define a partial ordering, yes? I.e. if Item1 appears before Item2 in one of the lists, it should be considered "bigger".

If this is correct, than the way to go is to first represent this in a more convenient form, e.g. a matrix `M`, such that `M[1][2]==1` if Item1 precedes Item2 in one of the list. Then we have a simple comparator function:

```
if M[X][Y] == 1:
    return 1 # X > Y
elif M[Y][X] == 1:
    return -1 # Y > X
else
    return 0 # the elements are not comparable
```

We can now sort the output according to this comparator.

You might want to run the transitive closure (Warshall's algorithm) on this matrix before sorting, in case there are, for example, lists Item1>Item3 and Item3>Item2, but no list where Item2 would appear together with Item1. Transitive closure would allow one to deduce from the two lists that Item1 should precede Item2.

Comment: What will happen if in list one I have: item1>item2>item3 and in list two I have: item3>item1?

Comment: Basically, it renders the ordering invalid, and the directed graph is not acyclic any more. One option would be to store the number of times one element occurs before another in the data, and then checking which ordering is more frequent. This is all a bit ad hoc, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would compose a weighted graph from the input (number of links between A>B is the weight), put that into an N*N matrix, and perform the power-iteration (GIYF) on the matrix.